# Evolution: how to remove calendar of other exchange user without deleting it from the server?

Tags: evolution, calendar

I use Evolution-EWS to connect to my companies MS-Exchange and have subscribed to one of my co-workers calenders via the "Subscribe Other User's Folder" in the context menu of my exchange folder.

However when I try to remove the calender via its context menu, Evolution only offers me to delete it completely from the server (which leaves me a bit flabbergasted, as that is an option I certainly would not expect to be exposed to the end user).

Is there a way to simply unsubscribe from the calender again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the Calender -> Delete -> Remove from Server

this does not actually delete the calender, it just removes the connection to the shared calendar.

Thomas